# Google sheet formulas (Excel)

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I wanna count no of students scored below 50 in their examination
I tried this,

```
=IF(C2:D2<50 THEN E2=E2+1)
```

But it didn't  worked generated error:(
[image: Her's My Sheet]

Comment: =IF(C2:D2<50,E2=E2+1)

Comment: If I'm not wrong you are entering formula in `Cell E2` and trying to update the same cell. Well that is not possible using formula and will require VBA, though formula you are using is also incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

`=COUNTIF(C2:D2;"<50")`

This link might be helpful:

https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en

Comment: What to do if I wanna count those who are absent as fail is there any OR operation available in google sheets ie =COUNTIF(C2:D2;"<50" OR "abs")

Comment: Plese try `countifs` for multiple conditions

Comment: =COUNTIFS(C2:E2,"<50",C2:E2,"=abs") tried it showed 0 instead of 2 i have one record less dhan 50 and another abs

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct syntaxis is:

```
IF(condition,value_case_true,value_case_false)
```

There is no "THEN"

;)

Answer (score 0):

There are two error in this formula

```
=IF(C2:D2<50,E2=E2+1)
```

**#value** (C2:D2<50) and **#ref** error (E2=E2+1)
E2 has no value

change it to :

```
=IF(sum(C2:D2)<50,D2+1)
```

change what condition you want but cannot put E2 itself "Circular Dependency Detected Error".